# Selecting a row in a UIPickerView dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I have an iPhone app that use UIPickerView and 3 buttons.

This picker has one component with 100 rows (0, 1, 2, ..., 98, 99).

I'd like to implement the code so that, when I press on the buttons

- button1: will make the picker select row 21th (which has value 20)
- button2: will make the picker select row 41th (which has value 40)
- button3: will make the picker select row 60th
  (which has value 60)

I know how to make the picker select a row when the view first load 
by put the following code in to viewDidLoad() method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad   
{  
    ........  
    [picker selectRow:50 inComponent:0 animated:YES];  
}
```

but I could not make the picker select the desired row when I tap the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I recreate the project and retype the code:

```
- (IBAction) goToRowTwenty  
 {   
    [picker selectRow:20 inComponent:0 animated:YES];   
    [timerPickerView reloadComponent:0];  
 }
```

and it works, I really don't know what happened, but thank you guys for answering my question.

Answer (score 4):

Hook the button to an action method, then in your action method simply call the same `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` method, i.e.

```
- (IBAction)button1Action {
    [picker selectRow:20 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

And you hook up the button to that method in Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I even call 'reloadComponent' from the picker but it still does not work. I must be missing something here. This is the code I use for 'button1' in my app.                                           - (IBAction) goToRowTwenty                                          {                                                                           [picker selectRow:20 inComponent:0 animated:YES];                [timerPickerView reloadComponent:0];                                }

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Sometomes you just don't see the obvious. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that picker is defined with "IBOutlet" as follows.  And connect the picker's referencing outlet to this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the same code that you have kept in viewDidLoad for selecting pickerRow on the event that get fires when button is clicked.

```
-(void)button1clickevent{
//FUNCTION MUST GET FIRE WHEN BUttON ! IS CLICKED
       [picker selectRow:50 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

HAPPY iCODING...

Comment: Yes, I did that. I even call 'reloadComponent' from the picker but it still does not work. I must be missing something here. This is the code I use for 'button1' in my app. - (IBAction) goToRowTwenty { [picker selectRow:20 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; [timerPickerView reloadComponent:0]; }

Comment: and whats this timepickerView here... reload your picker [picker reloadComponent:0] not [timepicker reloadComponent:0]; Also theres no need to reload picker. Please check out whether your picker is really binded with the picker in xib.